# How can I watch imported SASS files using Webpack?

Tags: sass, webpack

The problem I am encountering a great number of imported files.  I am trying to slowly inject webpack into a legacy site.  There are many global stylesheets:

```
require('../../../Content/Ones/_forms.scss');
require('../../../Content/Ones/_grid.scss');
require('../../../Content/Ones/_panels.scss');
require('../../../Content/Ones/one.scss');
require('../../../Content/Ones/_grid_tools.scss');
```

Is there a way to avoid this? I might be just looking at this from the wrong angle because I can't seem to find a question that matches my use case.

Please advise, Thanks!

Comment: Are you wondering about watching changes to imported SASS files, or wondering how to avoid having a bunch of global SASS?

Comment: I actually wondered about both, but I want to watch the imported global files.  The structure isn't really "component" based.

Answer (score 0):

The SASS files you import (whether you import them from a JS file or another SASS file) are part of your webpack dependency tree, so they should all be watched automatically. If they're not, would you mind adding some more info to your question about your app structure and webpack config?

As for reducing the number of global SASS imports, there are a few ways to do that, but making a good choice here really depends on how your app is structured.

Side question: Is there a reason you're adding webpack to this site? Anything in particular you're hoping to gain? I ask because if it's not a component-based SPA, you might not be getting very much out of webpack, and it may not be worth the trouble.

Comment: This is probably right.  My use case maybe a bit incorrect for the type of benefit from a Hybrid (.NET Routing instead of SPA) Based Legacy app.  We're trying to convert from an old .NET based site into a newer structure slowly.  The CSS was written off the bat with global's due to inexperienced web component based development.  I'm not sure if I should go towards the Gulp (task runner) route instead.  The documentation mentions that if we decide to use webpack.